# Does Azure Storage Emulator Support File Shares?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-files

I have the Azure Storage Emulator running but it currently looks like (as of v5.6.0.0) that it only supports Blob, Queue, and Table storage:

`BlobEndpoint: http://127.0.0.1:10000/
QueueEndpoint: http://127.0.0.1:10001/
TableEndpoint: http://127.0.0.1:10002/`

The confusing part is when you configure a local connection via the desktop Azure Storage Explorer by selecting `Attached to a local emulator`, there's an option for Files port.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the docs

> The File service and SMB protocol service endpoints are not currently supported in the storage emulator.

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/storage/common/storage-use-emulator.md#differences-between-the-storage-emulator-and-azure-storage

Comment: There's a feature request for it here: https://github.com/Azure/Azurite/issues/113