# Is it possible to add file end point to Local Azure Storage Emulator

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-storage-emulator, azure-emulator

I am trying to test some of the changes locally on Azure storage emulator and try to attach the storage emulator to The storage explorer.

[image]

But in the storage Explorer shows only the list of table, blobs and queues endpoint, not file endpoint.

[image]

So I can add file endpoint. Or it is not possible?

Comment: Any update this issue?

Comment: I think currently there is not support , and i have mark your reply as answered .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, Azure Storage Emulator does not Support File Share.

Refer to:https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/storage/common/storage-use-emulator.md#differences-between-the-storage-emulator-and-azure-storage

> The File service and SMB protocol service endpoints are not currently supported in the storage emulator.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51749573/does-azure-storage-emulator-support-file-shares) is a similar issue, you could refer to it.